# What long-looking worms are the Klingons always eating?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, food

I was reading an article on arstechnica [here](http://arstechnica.com/science/2016/03/this-could-be-the-food-of-the-future-if-you-can-handle-it/?comments=1) and I remembered that in *Star Trek*, Klingons are shown eating a lot of long looking worms.

Anyone know what they are? Has anyone tried them?  Or they just acting, and the people are not actually eating the worms?

Comment: I think it safe to assume that, out-of-universe, the actors were not actually eating live worms.  (Which is not to say that people have not been known to eat worms on occasion.  But if that's what you're after, Reality TV is probably a better bet than Star Trek.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston : Not looking forward to eating them...Just curious...Because it looked quite original when the actors ate.

Comment: Here is the episode / scene we are first introduced to gag'h: (TNGS2E8: A Matter of Honor) - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoOfjGqo5EY

Comment: Others have already answered the question, but I'll offer a small linguistic note: The word **ghargh** is in _The Klingon Dictionary_, with the definition "serpent, worm", suggesting that either word might be appropriate translations. It seems the script writers interpreted it as "serpent worm", and pronounced it _gahg_. In _Klingon for the Galactic Traveler_, Marc Okrand made this into a new word, **qagh**, which specifically refers to **gharghmey** which are served in a particular fashion.

Comment: @loghaD : That's some intricate knowledge of Klingons you got, which planet you come from.. :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These are serpent worms, commonly called *gagh* by the Klingons.

There are different types of *gagh*, such as one kind that jumps, one that wriggles, and one that has feet.

Klingons usually eat it alive, but it can also be served stewed, or cold.

It's a safe bet that the actors were **not** eating real worms. <s>If anything, it was probably spaghetti.</s>

From the *Star Trek Cookbook*:

> There was another dish, the famous gagh, that always had to look like living worms, especially when the Klingon warriors scooped them up in their hands. Orriginally the gagh were white, not whole wheat, Oriental udon noodles that I dyed brown with soy sauce. As a base, you can use soy sauce, some sesame salad dressing, the salad dressing you use for Chinese Chicken Salad, or the brown stir-fry sauce that really clings to the noodles and acts like a dye but really isn't.

[image: live gagh]

-Live *gagh*

Comment: That looks freakish... But thank you for the answer.. :-)

Comment: "There's nothing worse than half-dead gagh!"

Comment: Served cold? Only if it's a side dish to a main of **revenge**.

Comment: Looks like Udon to me. Confirmed by [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xwzZIdX2hMC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=gagh+prop+made+of&source=bl&ots=ZWX1i_X5Ye&sig=OfRxMltEav00rDl8o0TvYKSOZT8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ_ZmwubHLAhWltoMKHUg0CigQ6AEIDTAB#v=onepage&q=gagh%20prop%20made%20of&f=false)

Comment: @Paul Good find- probably should put that in an answer!

Comment: This meal would trigger my **gagh** reflex.

Comment: Don't forget about *gagh*s bigger brother, *racht*.

Comment: Guys... Stop doing silly jokes and **gaghs**

Answer (score 21):

To add to the in-universe answers, it seems like the prop *gagh* is made from Japanese Udon noodles, according to [*the Star Trek cookbook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xwzZIdX2hMC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=gagh+udon&source=bl&ots=ZWX1i_08Zf&sig=MfHVg_bs3jk2L4FR49E-uln5TD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYweiUzbHLAhVinoMKHUoOA1wQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=gagh%20udon&f=false), page 59:

> There was another dish, the famous *gagh*, that always had to look like living worms, especially when the Klingon warriors scooped them up in their hands. Originally the *gagh* were white, not whole wheat, Oriental udon noodles that I dyed brown with soy sauce. As a base, you can use soy sauce, some sesame salad dressing, the salad dressing you use for Chinese Chicken Salad, or the brown stir-fry sauce that really clings to the noodles and acts like a dye but really isn't.

Probably pretty tasty, though he later goes on to say that he mainly was going for the look and the taste is secondary. If you're interested, [here](http://www.suziethefoodie.com/star-treks-infamous-gagh-newsletter-coming-this-weekend/) is an account of someone who made and ate it.

Comment: Any word on what made it move to give it the "still alive" look?

Comment: @Michael: They used a kinaesthetic agent to give it a little oomph :)

Comment: @Michael I don't actually have the book, I am just going by the linked Google Books preview. He doesn't mention trying to make them move or anything.

Comment: If it's made from udon noodles, it's pretty much tasty by definition (</unbiased, objective fact>). I wonder why he says “white, not whole wheat, Oriental udon noodles”, though: udon noodles are by definition made from regular wheat flour and are very white. If you make them with whole grain flour, they're not udon noodles. (And for those who didn't know: if you pour clear [dashi broth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashi) over cooled udon noodles, you get **bukkake**. So there's that. I'll leave it up to you whether that adds to or detracts from the deliciousness of _gagh_.)

Answer (score 15):

That would probably be the Klingon delicacy known as [Gagh](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gagh). Looks pretty tasty!

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There is also *racht* (which nobody else mentioned), which is essentially a larger version of *gagh*. I'm not sure if any in universe details are given on their relation. The only time I recall it being seen was in DS9's episode *Melora*, as well as when Jadzia Dax ordered it in DS9's *Playing God*:

As for *gagh*, expanding on the other answers here: There are many varieties. I'm not sure if any other types are detailed in universe, but from the DS9 episode *Prodigal Daughter* which I just coincidentally happened to watch last night, there is at least:

- Torgud Gagh, these wiggle on the way down, compared to:
- Filden Gagh, these squirm on the way down, compared to:
- Meshta Gagh, these jump on the way down
- Bithool Gagh, these have feet
- Wistan Gagh, these are packed in targ blood (targs are a commonly referenced animal native to the Klingon home world, conceptually similar to a wild boar).

The dialog in that episode implies that there are at least 51 varieties:

> KIRA: How much gagh did she order?
>       ODO: Fifty one cases.
>       EZRI: Each containing a different variety.
>       KIRA: There are varieties of gagh?
>       EZRI: Oh, yes. I can remember what each one tastes like, and the way they feel when you swallow them. Torgud gagh wiggles. Filden gagh squirms. Meshta gagh jumps.
>       (Ezri gags.)
>       BASHIR: Are you all right?
>       ...
>       EZRI: Bithool gagh has feet. Flush it out the airlock. All of it.
>       ODO: Environmental regulations.
>       KIRA: Why don't you just give it to Martok?
>       EZRI: He'd insist on sharing it with me as a point of honour. Wistan gagh is packed in targ blood. I have to go now. See you later.

I do not claim to know the difference between "squirm" and "wiggle", but those were the words Ezri Dax used to describe them.

I also know that Klingon's prefer lively, squirming gagh and racht - complaints along the lines of "this gagh is barely moving, it's half dead" are often seen. I also recall an episode of TNG -- *A Matter of Honor* -- where Riker sampled *stewed* gagh on the Enterprise, only to be surprised by the relative liveliness of *fresh* gagh later served to him on a Klingon ship:

> RIKER: A Klingon delicacy. That's heart of targ -- this is pipius claw. And this is stewed "gagh."
>       PULASKI: "Gagh"?
>       RIKER: Serpent worms... would you like to know how they're prepared?

... later, on a Klingon ship ...

> RIKER: This is "gagh," isn't it?
>       KLAG: Very good. You did some research on our nutritional choices.
>       RIKER: Yes... but this is still moving.
>       KLAG: "Gagh" is always best when served live. (covering smile) Would you like something "easier"?
>       RIKER: Easier?
>       KLAG: If Klingon food is too strong for you, perhaps I could get one of the females to breast feed you.

Comment: Why do I feel like Riker would have preferred that meal?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It was a [classic moment](https://youtu.be/bBg3uBGHCWg?t=108) (and hilariously awkward). I think he made up for it when he took command of the ship!

Comment: "One... or both?"

Comment: I think "live" means it's taken on in the classic manner ans stored live until used. That's *much* harder than just getting it from the replicator. And that might be the point.